# Disabling the shift keyboard shortcut for dashboard

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, dashboard

I am using an application that requires me to frequently type in mixed-case strings starting with multiple uppercase characters, and the easiest way to do this is to hold shift and type them. However, whenever I hold the shift key for too long, Dashboard pops up and does not allow me to type anything more until I get rid of it. I looked in system settings, but I couldn't find that option. Is this possible and how can I do it?

Comment: Though it's not a helpful answer, I'm curious as to why you don't use Caps Lock instead.

Comment: (iOS development is What I'm doing) I have to frequently type things like NSURLConnection and NSXMLParser, and (if I hesitate) even UIActivityIndicatorView triggers it.

Comment: That is a perfectly good reason! Incidentally, I've held down Shift on my Mac (for 30 seconds) and Dashboard doesn't show up at all. I am curious about this too.

Comment: I edited the question to clarify these strings.

Comment: I am voting to close this question because it no longer is applicable (I don't use this computer any more) and I stopped being able to reproduce this over remote desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an accessibilty option 'Sticky Keys'.

> And, for those who find it difficult to use a mouse, every Mac computer includes Mouse Keys, Slow Keys, and Sticky Keys, which adapt the computer to the user’s needs and capabilities. http://www.apple.com/accessibility/

Look for Universal Access in the system preferences and then Sticky Keys.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Access